# Is There Any Method To Push Object To Array Uniquely?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, mongo-shell

Is there any method to push object to array uniquely with 1 method by ***ES6*** ?

### For Ex:

```
MyArray.pushUniquely(x);
```

### Or good to use old version like ?  :

```
MyMethod(x) {

    if ( MyArray.IndexOf(x) === -1 )
        MyArray.Push(x);

}
```

Is there any method to push uniquely by ES6 ?

Comment: Since you tagged this with `mongo-shell`, it may be worth noting that MongoDB has the [`$.addToSet` operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/#up._S_addToSet) for collections.

Comment: I have to use iterative query at this situation. Querying, then taking some ids, and then querying again. Finally, i have to reduce all of them as unique.

Answer (score 2):

Use a `Set` collection instead of an array.

```js
var mySet = new Set([1, 2, 3]);

mySet.add(4);
mySet.add(3);
mySet.add(0)

console.log(Array.from(mySet))
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `includes` (I've made an extension of a method so you can use it on all arrays):

```
Array.prototype.pushUnique(item) {
    if (!this.includes(item)) this.push(item);
}
```

Alternatively, use a `Set`:

```
mySet.add(x); //Will only run if x is not in the Set
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use lodash uniq method.

```js
var uniq = _.uniq([1,2,3,4,5,3,2,4,5,1])

console.log(uniq)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

If the array is an array of objects you can do

```js
const arr = [{
    name: 'Robert',
    age: 26
  },
  {
    name: 'Joshua',
    age: 69
  }
]

Array.prototype.pushUniquely = function (item) {
  const key = 'name';
  const index = this.findIndex(i => i[key] === item[key]);
  if (index === -1) this.push(item);
}

arr.pushUniquely({
  name: 'Robert',
  age: 24
});

console.log(arr);
```

If it's just an array of string or number then you can do:

```
Array.prototype.pushUniquely = function (item) {
    if (!this.includes(item)) this.push(item);
}
```